# PowerBi create a column with differences between two different dates and locations

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've have an issue where I want a column that shows the differences between months but only for the different location.  I have an example below where there are three locations with records for different dates. I have manually put in the differences.

[image]

Normally this would just be an if statment if (location == the same) then n1-n2.

does anyone know how to do this in dax or in the query editor.

```html
Date Location numbers difference
07/02/2019 berlin 58047 0.00 
27/03/2019 berlin 81086 23039.00 
30/03/2019 berlin 21400 -59686.00 
31/03/2019 berlin 77289 55889.00 
01/01/2019 london 51101 0.00 
01/02/2019 london 27815 -23286.00 
10/03/2019 london 62659 34844.00 
14/03/2019 london 49617 -13042.00 
22/03/2019 london 53744 4127.00 
24/04/2019 london 50337 -3407.00 
22/01/2019 Paris 74002 0.00 
02/02/2019 Paris 76931 2929.00 
13/03/2019 Paris 62430 -14501.00 
16/03/2019 paris 76002 13572.00 
21/03/2019 paris 71528 -4474.00 
26/04/2019 Paris 12577 -58951.00
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share data in text format? It will be much helpful.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar i've added the data as a code snippet dont know any other way on here to add it

Comment: Thanks, Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to filter the table to the current location and find the top 1 value, order by date descending, the calculated column should be:

```
Difference = 
VAR CurrentLocation = test[ Location]
VAR CurrentDate = test[Date]
VAR CurrentNumber = test[ numbers]
VAR LastValue =   
    SUMX(
        TOPN(
            1,
            FILTER (
                ALL(test),
                test[ Location] = CurrentLocation && 
                test[Date] < CurrentDate
            ),
            test[Date], DESC
        ),
        test[ numbers]
    )
VAR Difference = CurrentNumber - LastValue
RETURN 
    IF(
        ISBLANK(LastValue), 
        0, 
        Difference
    )
```

Hope this helps.